# Oscillation of a particle due to electrostatic attraction of 4 rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator

I came across this problem in a previous year's version of my AP Physics test, about oscillations and waves. Here is the problem:

[image]

My solution:
Since we know $\frac{F}{m} = a, -\omega^2x = \frac{-40x}{(4x^2+4)(\sqrt{2+4x^2}}, \omega =\sqrt{\frac{-40}{(4x^2+4)\sqrt{2+4x^2}}}.$

 
Since we know that it starts at the extreme position, the position equation of SHM is $x(t) = 0.05\cos\omega t.$ Thus we set $x(t)=0.02$ and see that:

$0.4 = \cos\omega t.$ Plugging  $x$ into the $\omega$ equation above we get that $\cos 2.17t = 0.4$. From here, should I use the period of $\cos$ to find the second solution? Or should I just take the $\arccos$ of this equation?

Thank you.

Comment: Does in any way help that :
$$
F(x)=-\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V(x)}{\mathrm{d} x}
\tag{01}
$$
where
$$
V(x)=5\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\sqrt{2x^{2}+1}\right)  
\tag{02}
$$
$x$(meters),$F$(Newtons),$V$(Joules).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the Figure above we see the graphs of the force $\:F(x)\:$ and the potential $\:V(x)\:$ in the region $\:x \in (-5m,+5m)\:$ far from simple harmonic motion.

In the Figure below we see the graphs of the force $\:F(x)\:$ and the potential $\:V(x)\:$ in the region $\:x \in (-0.05m,+0.05m)\:$ with great accuracy simple harmonic motion. Try to find the "spring constant" $\:k\:$ to find what the problem asks for.

[image]

[image]

Comment: $...\grave{\alpha}\varsigma\:\: \lambda\omicron\gamma\alpha\rho\iota\acute{\alpha}\sigma\eta \:\: \tau\grave{\omicron}\nu\:\: \alpha\rho\iota\theta\mu\grave{\omicron}\nu\:\: \tau\omicron\overset{_\boldsymbol{\frown}}{\upsilon}\:\:\theta\eta\rho\acute{\iota}\omicron\upsilon\dot \:\:\delta\iota\acute{\omicron}\tau\iota\:\;\epsilon\overset{_\boldsymbol{\frown}}{\acute{\iota}} \nu\alpha\iota \:\:\alpha\rho\iota\theta\mu\grave{\omicron}\varsigma\:\:\alpha\nu\theta\rho\acute{\omega}\pi\omicron\upsilon : 5\sqrt{2}   $

Answer (score 0):

​Where does it say in the problem that the motion is simple harmonic?

For simple harmonic motion the restoring force $F$ has to satisfy the equation $F=-m\omega^2x$ where $\omega$ is a constant independent of $x$.
Such a relationship would produce a force $F$ against displacement $X$ graph which was a straight line through the origin of gradient $-m\omega^2$.

The given force does not satisfy this condition as shown in the graph below.

[image]

Noting that $x$ in the force equation is in metres and the displacements are in centimetre you are only going to be concerned with the part of the graph close to the origin.
By inspection the graph looks like a straight line and does have a negative gradient.

So what you need to do is a Taylor expansion of your equation for the force about $x=0$ and ignore any terms of order $x^2$ and above.
If you do not know how to do that then you can use the fact that $x<1$ and so $x^2\ll 1$ to simplify the force equation.

You will then have a relationship of the form $F \approx - k x$ which would give you simple harmonic motion.
This will enable you to find a value for $\omega$ and hence solve the problem.

Comment: I know how to use a Taylor Expansion, but I highly doubt that that was the intended solution; it is supposed to be an algebra-based class. Also, I realize that it is not really a simple harmonic motion, but it in the given interval it can be approximated as one. Thank you for the suggestion about "ignoring" the x^2 terms, it helped.